# Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, xcode, классы, случайные-числа, инкапсуляция

Всем привет. Можно сказать я ещё маслёнок, но базовые понятия и костыли пишу.
Такой вопрос: Моя задача - есть класс Player, у него 2 поля (Name и Mode)
И метод выводящий его поля в консоль. В основном скрипте есть массив состоящий из элементов класса player, а так же класс рандома.
Этот скрипт должен изменять Mode определённого Player элемента на Murder и Officer, причём в массиве не может быть более 2 элементов с модом Murder и Officer, поэтому я поставил проверку в условии, а в else написал повторение метода в котором заключен этот оператор if.
Моя программа работает, но иногда в консоль пишет ошибку из заголовка, что делать?
Снизу под скриптом приложен класс Player.Если здесь нужна инкапсуляция то напишите зачем.

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp6
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            Player[] plyr = new Player[3];
            plyr[0] = new Player();
            plyr[1] = new Player();
            plyr[2] = new Player();


            int off = rnd.Next(0, 2);
            int mur = rnd.Next(0, 2);

            plyr[off].Mode = "Officer";
            Randomizer();

             void Randomizer()
            {

                   if (plyr[mur].Mode != "Officer")
                    {
                        plyr[mur].Mode = "Murder";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Randomizer();
                    }


            }
            for (int i = 0; i < plyr.Length; i++)
            {

                plyr[i].GetInfo();

            }


            Console.ReadKey();


        }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp6
{
    class Player
    {
        public string Name  = "Standart";
        public string Mode = "Civilian";
        public void GetInfo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Name + " " + Mode);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: У вас в `Randomizer()` бесконечная рекурсия

Comment: можно пояснить как её исправить?

Comment: что значит исправить? Ну, уберите вызов функции самой себя - не будет рекурсии

Comment: да, рекурсия пропала, но теперь программа не всегда выполняет свою задачу, иногда выводятся 2 Civilian и один officer хотя такого не должно быть. В этом случае должно быть Civilian Officer Murder, но не всегда поэтому я и задал вопрос

Comment: ну так вы поглядите на свою функцию `Randomizer()`. Что она делает? Она выполняет какую то проверку, и либо что то устанавливает, либо вызывает сама себя. А теперь представьте, что вы вызываете эту функцию, когда `plyr[mur].Mode == "Officer"`. Как в этом случае функция себя поведет?

Comment: Спасибо, благодаря вам я подумал над этой проблемой более глобально)

Comment: пожалуйста (+ 5 символов)